# Why does my function not return the data I expect?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

Here's my code, creating an array from a text file.  If I trace it inside the function "onloaded", I see my array. But it returns me nothing outside the function. Why?

```
var myTextLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var myArray:Array = new Array();


myTextLoader.load(new URLRequest("list.txt"));
myTextLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);

function onLoaded(e:Event) {
     myArray = e.target.data.split(/\n/);
     // if trace(myArray); here - I see my array.    
}

trace(myArray); // - output is clear, also it can't define a property, if I'm looking for .length
```

Comment: Oy, please don't use txtspeak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the order of events that is occurring in your program:

1. myArray is being created.
2. myTextLoader starts to load the contents list.txt.
3. An event listener is added to myTextLoader, which will cause a function to be executed when  list.txt is finished loading.
4. You trace the contents of myArray. There is nothing currently in myArray.
5. myTextLoader finishes loading list.txt
6. The onLoaded function is called
7. Data is added to myArray

---

To summarize, myArray is empty when you're trying to trace it. If you want to wait until the contents of list.txt are added to the array, then just put your loop into the onLoaded function instead.

**Option 1:**

```
var myTextLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var myArray:Array = new Array();


myTextLoader.load(new URLRequest("list.txt"));
myTextLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);

function onLoaded(e:Event) 
{
     myArray = e.target.data.split(/\n/);
     for (var i:int = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
     {
          trace(myArray[i]);
     }  
}
```

---

If you need to access the array later on, from another function, one solution is to store the array inside a variable with greater scope. In the below example, after the onLoaded function executes, you could then access the array from myArrayLoopFunction().

**Option 2:**

```
public class Main extends MovieClip
{
    public var myArray:Array = new Array();

    public function Main() 
    {
        var myTextLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

        myTextLoader.load(new URLRequest("list.txt"));
        myTextLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);

        function onLoaded(e:Event) 
        {
             myArray = e.target.data.split(/\n/);
        }
    }

    public function myArrayLoopFunction()
    {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
        {
            trace(myArray[i]);
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. But actually my main task is to work with a loop through the array. But my loop returns me nothing. How can i work with my loop? Should I set Timer? Or what people usually do in this situation? What should I read about in manual?

Comment: My post is now updated to include two ways to loop through the array. Both of those could potentially solve your issue, depending on what your issue is. Try them both out, and tell me if you can't get one of them to work. As for AS3 documentation, I guess you could read up on [variable scope](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9d.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f8c).

Comment: Pikamander2 Thank you very many! :D Now I remember that I've seen this 'trick' many times in courses... Yeah, always wrap everything in functions, then call them. Now I know what for :D. I called myArrayLoopFunction() from onLoaded function and it worked. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it returns nothing outside the function is that is has no data in it. That is because the data has not yet been loaded into the array. Your `trace(myArray)` outside the function will execute immediately when the data has not yet been saved, but your `trace(myArray)` inside the function which is a callback function that executes when the `load` function on the `URLLoader` is done, when you have loaded the file and therefore has data.